# Excluding from a Cypher query paths that go through a specific type of node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

what I need is to refine this query:

```
MATCH 
(u:User)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(c:Company)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(tc:UserView)
WHERE NOT (u:User)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(c:Company)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(:User)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(tc:UserView)
AND u.entityId=$userId and tc.entityId=$targetUserViewId
RETURN tc
```

I need to find UserView nodes **directly visible from User u without passing through another User**.

**EDIT: I'M NOT searching "what users are directly pointing to a given view". I want to know what views can be reached from a user passing through his own attached company and potentially other nodes (not presented in the example graph). See sample data and the last phrase of the question for a reference of the intended result.**

The query works fine if there is a single path to the UserView: if the path is direct, tc is returned; else, if the path goes through another user, no result is returned.

**The problem arises if there are more paths from u to tc, some legal, and some not: I want that tc is returned, because at least a good path exists, but I get no result.**

I understand that my query is wrong, because it says "search a tc that can't be accessed passing from another user", but what I really need is "search a tc that can be accessed in some manner without passing from another user"...

How can I fix my query?

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 0,
"labels": [
        "Tenant",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "Tenant 2b2fa6af-b18d-4839-bb61-1657a8573b37",
"entityId": "2b2fa6af-b18d-4839-bb61-1657a8573b37",
"id": "a5910cbe-0084-4e71-a722-724653b96a4e",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.Tenant:2b2fa6af-b18d-4839-bb61-1657a8573b37",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 1,
"labels": [
        "Company",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "Company d88cac2a-3c11-4088-8f9c-a6a44edf7023",
"entityId": "d88cac2a-3c11-4088-8f9c-a6a44edf7023",
"id": "2d5e3c31-ff86-410d-8aa5-6d638a38141b",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.company.Company:d88cac2a-3c11-4088-8f9c-a6a44edf7023",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 2,
"labels": [
        "User",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "User 76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3",
"entityId": "76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3",
"id": "00b77fc9-7c90-4e89-ae24-3fe2468afea5",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.user.User:76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 3,
"labels": [
        "Tenant",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "Tenant 7b8f4284-3e55-4e40-a8e8-6aee0b22dc97",
"entityId": "7b8f4284-3e55-4e40-a8e8-6aee0b22dc97",
"id": "55ad9591-0ec1-44b4-ba20-ff1218e0edce",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.Tenant:7b8f4284-3e55-4e40-a8e8-6aee0b22dc97",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 4,
"labels": [
        "Company",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "Company 9eddb71f-1126-443f-8e87-bf0ff14ef582",
"entityId": "9eddb71f-1126-443f-8e87-bf0ff14ef582",
"id": "ccc3e2e7-2001-401d-b199-1aa2e3b99d28",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.company.Company:9eddb71f-1126-443f-8e87-bf0ff14ef582",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 5,
"labels": [
        "User",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "User ffe8ac6a-b1fd-43a2-bb5c-112aba2e5288",
"entityId": "ffe8ac6a-b1fd-43a2-bb5c-112aba2e5288",
"id": "eec0daf3-52c5-4ebc-8e4d-2a93316ea40b",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.user.User:ffe8ac6a-b1fd-43a2-bb5c-112aba2e5288",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 6,
"labels": [
        "Company",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "Company 0738f2f7-2810-4358-a291-94a5e919469d",
"entityId": "0738f2f7-2810-4358-a291-94a5e919469d",
"id": "5657308e-a20e-4199-b92b-5659f36c39a9",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.company.Company:0738f2f7-2810-4358-a291-94a5e919469d",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 7,
"labels": [
        "User",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "User 5c4fef7f-1a41-4b09-a0f5-2034510dcf92",
"entityId": "5c4fef7f-1a41-4b09-a0f5-2034510dcf92",
"id": "d0b9798c-b7de-4761-a5a7-eaed4ca8a058",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.user.User:5c4fef7f-1a41-4b09-a0f5-2034510dcf92",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 8,
"labels": [
        "UserView",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "UserView 72bed633-c422-40f9-a7e1-cb41af27d70a",
"entityId": "72bed633-c422-40f9-a7e1-cb41af27d70a",
"id": "c5690b5a-5376-47fe-82dc-ea91799175f6",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.user.UserView:72bed633-c422-40f9-a7e1-cb41af27d70a",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "n": {
"identity": 9,
"labels": [
        "UserView",
        "VisibilityGroup"
      ],
"properties": {
"name": "UserView fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5",
"entityId": "fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5",
"id": "185f1b3f-8737-4ef0-b0af-bdee05352d5a",
"entityRef": "com.tierra.userservice.model.entity.user.UserView:fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5",
"isViewItem": false
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now execute:

```
MATCH 
(u:User)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(c:Company)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(tc:UserView)
WHERE NOT (u:User)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(c:Company)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(:User)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(tc:UserView)
AND u.entityId='76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3' and tc.entityId='fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5'
RETURN tc
```

**This returns nothing, I would like to have the view fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5, id=9 because a path exists between the user and the view NOT passing through another User.**

Comment: please give us sample data and expected results. Thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy I added data and results thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick, I hope it's correct... but I think there should be a much better solution using another description of the path...

```
MATCH p=
(u:User)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(c:Company)-[:CAN_SEE*]->(tc:UserView)
WHERE  u.entityId='76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3' and tc.entityId='fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5'
AND none(x IN NODES(p) WHERE ( 'User' IN LABELS(x) and x<>u  ))
RETURN tc
```

Comment: After many tests I can confirm that this query does what I want; I'm still not convinced that it is the best way to express what I need. Any other, more coincise way?

Answer (score 0):

> ... find UserView nodes directly visible from User u without passing
> through another User

```
MATCH (tc:UserView)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(u:User)
WHERE u.entityId='76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3'
RETURN tc
```

Or, if you want to limit it to a specific `UserView`:

```
MATCH (tc:UserView)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(u:User)
WHERE
  u.entityId='76f1bf95-6819-4aea-b1c3-4d138eb40cd3' AND
  tc.entityId='fbd5cb12-0685-46e6-a672-2770f2140bf5'
RETURN tc
```

Comment: Hi, the graph is more complex because there are default views attached to companies, so your solution doesn't work. I edit the question to explain better, sorry. What I need is a way to search all nodes of a given type in a path, excluding paths that go through the same type of node I'm searching for. See my answer: I search a similar query without predicates, if possible.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Are you saying that the following pattern does not exist in your DB? `(tc:UserView)<-[:CAN_SEE]-(u:User)`

Comment: they can exist, in fact as you can see one of the users has a direct connection with a user view; but I need that a path passing from company works (see example): (user)<--(company)-->(anything-not-user)-->(anything-not-user)-->(userview) must work